# Why HashMap is not good for a big dataset of integer keys?

Tags: java, arrays

I've a non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given. The array contains an odd number of elements, and each element of the array can be paired with another element that has the same value, except for one element that is left unpaired.

For example, in array A such that below:

```
A[0] = 9 , A[1] = 3 , A[2] = 9 , A[3] = 3 , A[4] = 9 , A[5] = 7 , A[6] = 9
```

I need to write a functon that returns the value of the unpaired element.

One of my first native solutions was to create a hashmap structure with unique keys - N integers of given array and iterate through the array adding values if the key is already exists in the hashmap. After all the key that has only 1 at it's value field is the unpaired element.

I know that the hashcode of Integer is it's int unique value...
So I soposed that there will not be a duplicate keys of different Integers..So I supposed that there will not be a duplicate keys for different Integers..But for a big sets of data this solution does not work...I think this has something to do with load factor.
But I can't get on it. I don't need an alterntive solution, becouse I have it already, I just want to understand what's wrong with hashmap when we use a big sets of integer keys..
Here is my code and thank you very much!:
Map a = new HashMap();

```
       for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++) {

           if(a.containsKey(A[i])){
               a.put(A[i], a.get(A[i])+1);     
           }else  a.put(A[i], 1);      

       }

       for (Integer i : a.keySet()) {
              if(a.get(i)==1)
                  return i;
            }

       return -1;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HHLM.png)

Answer (score 2):

> I think this has something to do with load factor.

No, the problem is not in the `HashMap`, it's in the way you are using it.

Your solution is not complete because it assumes all the pairs are unique. i.e. it assumes there can be at most one pair of 9 (which is not true in the example you posted, which contains 2 pairs of 9).

Having multiple identical pairs will not necessarily result in a wrong answer, but what
if, for example, there are 3 9's, two of them are paired, but the 3rd is not? Your solution won't find it, since `a.get(9)` would return `3`, but you check if it's equal to `1`.

Instead of checking

```
if(a.get(i)==1)
```

you should check if it's odd

```
if(a.get(i)%2==1)
```

Comment: Ok, you mean if I've several pairs of this key but still it isn't  odd..like {5,5,5,3,3}, nice, didn't think about this)) Checking..

Comment: Eran!!! Thank you very much!! I knew that there can be a lot of not unique pairs, but I missed that in addition to one odd number, there may still be the same pair of the same number. It shows me now 100% of task score, correctness and performance. Kol ha kavod!